# Query.executeUpdate() results in XAResource exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, jakarta-ee

I'm running Spring and Hibernate's implementation of JPA on Sun's GlassFish Enterprise Server with MySQL.

When I try to delete stuff from the database:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM SomeEntity e");
q.executeUpdate();
```

I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Got exception during XAResource.start:
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:115)
at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:69)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.openConnection(AbstractBatcher.java:550)
```

However, all other queries that invoke getResultList() works:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM SomeEntity e");
q.getResultList();
```

For some reason the JDBC driver can't get a connect for `executeUpdate()` yet it works for `getResultList()`. The application's MySQL account has all privileges including INSERT and DELETE.

Comment: Did you try using the driver that comes with your version of MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you are using jta-datasource. And I think, you have no transaction started. Or probably you have some problems with you datasources. So, you should test your datasources (you could define both jta-data-source and non-jta-data-source). And you need enshure that all updates are done in a transactional context.

Answer (score 0):

In general XAResource means that you are inside distributed transaction. You must use XA driver in this case for DB data source and connection (e.g. com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource)